# Show the outcome of decision tree in a confusionmatrix

Tags: r, decision-tree

I trying to predict the outcome of a match. Therefore Im using the rpart algoritm on a test and training set.

When im training my algoritm I do this:

```
 tree <- rpart(won ~ EXPG1 + EXPG2, data=training, method="class")
```

And with this I predict whether a match will have 0,1 or 2 as endresult.

```
 predict <- predict(tree, testing)
```

Which leads to the following result:

```
 head(predict)
       0         1         2
2  0.7368421 0.1578947 0.1052632
7  0.2777778 0.5000000 0.2222222
```

This all works fine. But now I would like to compare my results in confusionmatrix.

But this obviously doesnt work

```
confusionMatrix(testing$won, predict)
```

Because my testing$won column only contains 0,1 or 2. Any advice on how I can view my results in a confusionmatrix?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Pass the type into the predict function to return a class label:

```
predict <- predict(tree, testing, type = "class")
```

#### Full working example:

```
library(rpart)
library(caret)

data(iris)

mod <- rpart(Species~., iris)
p <- predict(mod, type="class")
```

#### And the output:

```
> confusionMatrix(p, iris$Species)
Confusion Matrix and Statistics

            Reference
Prediction   setosa versicolor virginica
  setosa         50          0         0
  versicolor      0         49         5
  virginica       0          1        45

Overall Statistics

               Accuracy : 0.96           
                 95% CI : (0.915, 0.9852)
    No Information Rate : 0.3333         
    P-Value [Acc > NIR] : < 2.2e-16      

                  Kappa : 0.94           
 Mcnemar's Test P-Value : NA             

Statistics by Class:

                     Class: setosa Class: versicolor Class: virginica
Sensitivity                 1.0000            0.9800           0.9000
Specificity                 1.0000            0.9500           0.9900
Pos Pred Value              1.0000            0.9074           0.9783
Neg Pred Value              1.0000            0.9896           0.9519
Prevalence                  0.3333            0.3333           0.3333
Detection Rate              0.3333            0.3267           0.3000
Detection Prevalence        0.3333            0.3600           0.3067
Balanced Accuracy           1.0000            0.9650           0.9450
```